# how to embed the Eclipse CSS Editor inside Eclipse MultiPageEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to embed the eclipse defualt CSS Editor inside a page of Eclipse MultiPage Editor. How to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `MultiPageEditorPart` and in its `createPages()` method, instantiate CSS editor part and add it with `MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(IEditorPart, IEditorInput)`.

See [this tutorial](http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/editors.html) which does the same with TextEditor.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Well how can I add some text manually inside the the CSS editor.

Comment: If that's a text user will be editing, then IEditorInput. Otherwise see IDocument API.

Comment: As the link provided by you , I added CSS Editor StructuredTextEditor inside MultiPageEditor at index 1, but I want to add some IFile content inside this editor likely to be string, but addPage only takes iEditorInput, so how to resolve this kind of scenario.

Comment: Check IEditorInput hierarchy for suitable class.

Comment: And maybe use different questions for your different questions.